# Setting the width of a div class using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking at some work which has a wonderful example of bad code; I'm unable to change the classes, so I have to deal with it.

I have three horizontal containers and 6 div classes using nice-selectbox. 3 are divs and set by some jQuery which I cannot touch and 3 are select classes.

I want to set the third div instance of nice-selectbox to width: 150% but I'm having no luck.

```
<div class="horizontal-three-container third">
    <h3 class="header-step">Heading</h3>
    <div class="nice-selectbox">
        <span class="select-text">Option 1</span>
        <select class="nice-selectbox" name="search">
            <option value="null">Please Select</option>
            <option id="search_1" value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
            <option id="search_2" value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option id="search_3" value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
$('div.nice-selectbox:eq(2)').css('width', '150%');

$('.third div.nice-selectbox').css('width', '150%');
```

And it's still not working. It only hits the select class.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

UPDATE with fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QAxLQ/1/

Works here it seems. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: where did you add the code??

Comment: have you tried width function: `$('div#somediv').width('70%');`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Top of the page. It definitely works, as it changes the element of the select class.

Comment: Option 3 is having IMPROPER HTML

Comment: Its working fine Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QAxLQ/

Comment: Have you tried giving $('div.nice-selectbox option:eq(2)').css('width', '150%'); ???

Comment: I don't see a third div instance in the given HTML.

Comment: @Jack I posted a snippet. No need to downvote me to oblivion :/

Comment: @steve I have - no luck.

Comment: What makes you think I downvoted your question? Also, please provide a fiddle with more HTML so that we can better help you.

Comment: @Jack Apologies if you didn't, yours was the last comment, coinciding with the downvote.

Comment: @Jack Updated with fiddle.

Comment: @DarkShadowAY I don't understand what you want... It works fine. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KpL8S/). Make sure you have jQuery included in your code. Make sure you have something like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it seems to be working in a JSFiddle it will be that you have not included jQuery on the page where it is being used.

Adding something like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Will fix the issue you are having. jQuery has to be included on the page via a script link or any jQuery you write will no work.

Just going to put a demo of it the code working with jQuery being included.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KpL8S/)

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. I had an older version. Thanks man!

Comment: @DarkShadowAY Its a common problem, this should be the first thing you do when using jQuery. Also your welcome.